# Making a copy constructor more flexible for ADT queue

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have constructed a copy constructor for an ADT queue. The copy constructor works fine.  I would want to improve my code, but I don't really know how to shorten it to make it more flexible. Code is given below:

```
template <typename T>
Queue <T>::Queue(const Queue & other)
{
    if (other.first == nullptr)
    {
        first = nullptr;
        nrOfElements = 0;
    }

   else
   {
    Node* saveFirst;
    Node* walker;
    first = other.first;
    walker = new Node(first->data);
    saveFirst = walker;
    while (first->next != nullptr)
    {
        walker->next = new Node(first->next->data);
        walker = walker->next;
        first = first->next;
    }
    walker->next = nullptr;
    first = saveFirst;
    }
this->nrOfElements = other.nrOfElements;
}
```

The class `Queue` also contains an inner private `Node` class which contains the pointers `first`, `next`, etc:

```
private:
    int nrOfElements;
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node* next;
        T data;
        Node(T data)
        {
            this->data = data;
        }
    };
    Node* first;
```

So, I would appreciate any suggestions/examples of how the copy constructor code above could be improved, as I'm a bit lost on the task.

Comment: Do you have a specific thought on flexibility or brevity that you are at loss on how to code? Personally, I don't see why this is inflexible, e.g..

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, not really. I handed in this code as a part of an assignment, but the teacher insisted that the code was not "good enough". He said that I could shorten this code about 50% but yeah... I don't know how.

Comment: A simple way is to iterate over the Queue `other` and call `Queue::PushBack(otherNodeData)`. So the code it as short as a function `void Print(const Queue<T>&);`

Answer (score 0):

try this one
may be in easier than your code

```
template <typename T>
Queue <T>::Queue(const Queue & other)
{
 Front =NULL;Rear=NULL;Count=0;
    Node *p= other.Front;
    while(p!=NULL){
        EnQueue(p->GetData());
        Rear->SetData(p->GetData());
        p=p->next;
    }
}
```

First we set NULL value to Front & Rear and 0 for Count second make new Node to get the data from every Node in old Queue and copy it to the new Queue.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: First we set NULL value to Front & Rear and 0 for Count 
second make new Node to get the data from every Node in old Queue and copy it to the new Queue